# Omnifaces Html5RenderKit: no input type="month" support

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Omnifaces [Html5RenderKit](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit) does not support [all input-type-attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#attr-input-type) like e.g. month or week.
Anybody knows if there's a reason for that? Or an update planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is an ongoing process and daily subject to changes. At the moment the `Html5RenderKit` was developed, those new attribues weren't supported on the major browsers IE/FF/Chrome.

OmniFaces 1.5 will add the new feature of the ability to specify additional custom (HTML5) attributes via a `<context-param>`. See also the "Configuration" section of the [`Html5RenderKit` page at the showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit).